# OpenShift Pro - Start Build Not Working

Tags: openshift

I have two web apps running on **OpenShift Pro**, they have been running nicely for a couple of weeks but today I had to make a very small change and push the change to OpenShift. The push failed...

Upon investigation I have discovered that **both apps** have the same problem (which is strange).

The problem:-

On the **Builds | AppName** page there is a button labelled **Start Build**. Clicking this button just produces an error message alert:-

> **An error occurred while starting the build. Reason: Error resolving
>   ImageStreamTag jboss-webserver30-tomcat8-openshift:1.2 in namespace
>   openshift: unable to find latest tagged image**

If I click on the latest build I go to the **Builds | AppName | Build #** page where there is a button labelled **Rebuild**. Clicking this button rebuilds successfully.

The real problem here is that this means that GitHub pushes fail to start a build, so development and changes are no longer possible...

Any ideas as to why **Start Build** no longer works?

I think it may be a problem at OpenShift as I have changed nothing recently...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into what happened but you can update your build configuration to use tag 1.3 or latest instead of 1.2.

[image]

Comment: I changed it to 'Latest' and as if by magic the GitHub push and build works again. Thanks for your help SteveS, it's much appreciated...

Comment: Great to hear you are working. We are rolling out a fix which should resolve this longer term. Sorry for the disruption.